# Height width of Captured image from Camera2 api

Tags: kotlin, android-camera2

I have captured image using Camera2 api. now when i try to retrieve same image information from content resolver, Height and Width returning null. Though i got other parameters like DATA, Bucket and so on.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you mean you are accessing the data using exif ?

Comment: yes fixed it by ExifInterface